# Match everything between parenthesis

Tags: php, regex

I currently have this regex

```
/^(@if([a-zA-z0-9.=(\s*)]+))/
```

I'm looking to match any string along the lines of `@if (expression)`, which includes strings like:

```
@if (name == false)
@if (1 == 1)
@if ((name == false) && 1 == 1)
@if (model.name)
@if (model|length > 5)
```

Yet the regex I have right now also accepts these strings:

```
@if (1 == 1)s
```

How would I fix it?

Comment: can't you just anchor the regexp to the end of the line with `$`? That will prevent anything after the close parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're dealing with nested brackets here you will need to use [recursive regex feature of PCRE regex](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php).

```
$s = '@if ((name == false) && 1 == 1)';
if (preg_match('/(@if) \s* ( \( (?: [^()]* | (?2) )* \) ) \s*$ /x', $s, $arr))
   print_r($arr);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => @if ((name == false) && 1 == 1)
    [1] => @if
    [2] => ((name == false) && 1 == 1)
)
```

**PS:** Due to sue `\s*$` in the end it won't match `@if ((name == false) && 1 == 1)foo`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the other answer was deleted. It gave `^@if\s?\(.*\)$` as a regexp, which would solve your problem with other characters at the end.

However, I would suggest for you to rethink your approach. You are experiencing an inherent limitation of Regular Expressions. You cannot count the number of open vs. closed brackets. Thus, any regexp would also validate `@if ()))`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-outer-brackets) has more details.

There are some [extensions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html) to regular expressions that allow for recursion, but I would avoid using that. Regexps are just not the right tool here.

Comment: What does counting parentheses or recursion have to do with the problem in the question?

Comment: Technically speaking, you're right. In that way, the (now deleted) answer which gave `^@if\s?\(.*\)$` was correct. However, I believe that it is more helpful to inform the OP of a more fundamental issue of what he's trying to do.

Comment: I tried the `^@if\s?\(.*\)$` yet it gives me `no ending delimiter found`. I'm using php 5.3, any ideas? And yes my approach might not be the right one, I'm trying to make a template lexer/parser for educational purposes. Which approach would you take?